# Displaying graphs on wall

Tags: monitoring, metrics, graphite

I have been using graphite to collect metrics and display on graphs

My question is how are people displaying these on wall mounted screens?

Can see anywhere where people talk about how this is done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have Graphite on Wallboards all around the office and in most cases people are just loading it up in a browser, but others have created custom html pages to load the graph images.

The folks at Atlassian have presented/posted on Wallboards a bunch.  Here is a pretty good slide deck on Wallboards:

http://www.slideshare.net/GoAtlassian/ltds3-information-radiators

It boils down to:

- Large display
- Easy to understand (at a glance)
- Always relevant
- Easy to update
- Aesthetically pleasing

For getting Graphite to display, it is as easy as leaving a browser open and leveraging tabs (and a tab revolver plugin - e.g. Revolver Tabs Chrome Ext) with some saved dashboard graphs.  This has worked for me in the past:

[image: Wallboard example]

You can geek out on how you run it (e.g. we used a Raspberry Pi, which you can see in the picture above) and keep it running.  Here is Atlassian again using an AppleTv: https://blogs.atlassian.com/2011/10/using_an_appletv_as_a_build_monitor/

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Those people usually display the dashboard using e.g. a browser in fullscreen mode. A software for this purpose might be [gdash](https://github.com/ripienaar/gdash).